# write PL/SQL blog statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

suppose that we have employees table, my aim is to write declare  -blog statement which increases salary of this employees by 10%, which has   salary more than average in department where it works, and by 20% if it has not more salary,
I think  code should be

```
begin
update employees e set e.salary=e.salary+e.salary*0.1;
where e.salary>(select avg(e.salary)  from employees e group by e.department_id);
update employees e set e.salary=e.salary+e.salary*0.1;
where e.salary<(select avg(e.salary)  from employees e group by e.department_id);



end;
```

but it returns  following list of errors,

```
Error starting at line 4 in command:
begin
update employees e set e.salary=e.salary+e.salary*0.1;
where e.salary>(select avg(e.salary)  from employees e group by e.department_id);
update employees e set e.salary=e.salary+e.salary*0.1;
where e.salary<(select avg(e.salary)  from employees e group by e.department_id);



end;
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 3, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WHERE" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
   null pragma raise return select update while with
   <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
   <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock
   insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
   merge pipe purge
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

please help me why?, is there necessary loop statement or?

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `;` on

```
update employees e set e.salary=e.salary+e.salary*0.1;
```

The `;` terminates the statement but you continue it with `WHERE`

Answer (score 2):

You have a semicolon (`;`) before `where`; semicolons close PL/SQL statements.

I also suggest that you format your statements in a way that makes it easier to read and harder to make a mistake:

```
update employees e set 
    e.salary=e.salary+e.salary*0.1 -- no semicolon here
where 
    e.salary > (
        select avg(e.salary)  
        from employees e 
        group by e.department_id
    );
```

Comment: can i do  it by if-then--else i have changed,but it writes that  0 rows updated,i think first when it updates,then at the same time it trys  to update second also,but maybe there is no such employees and totaly  it can't update any row  yes?

Comment: you can run the `select` subquery directly and see the average salary. also you can white a `select count(*) from employees e` instead of `update ...` with the same `where ...` clause and see how many records  would the update affect.